# Submit remote form to wordpress REST API and save data to custom post type

Tags: php, plugin-development, theme-development, ajax

I will use the wordperss REST API to submit a form that is part of SPA webapp made using vue. I have registered a custom post type to hold the submitted data, specifically I want to register some custom fields that will hold the submitted form fields.

I'm not sure on how to proceed, but after I've registered the post type, I think that I need to register a route `register_rest_route()` to manage the data when they are submitted using a POST request, but how I save them? will the `update_post_meta()` create the meta fields I want and `wp_insert_post()` save then the custom post type?

**UPDATE**

The code I'm using to register the endpoint is the following:

```
function resgister_custom_endpoint(){
 register_rest_route('mytheme/v1', 'p', array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'callback' => 'add_new_place'
 ));
}
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_custom_endpoint');

function add_new_place($request){
 // save meta and post code
}
```

The meta fields I want to store with the custom post type I've created to manage the form are:

```
$_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['place_name'], $_POST['place_type'], $_POST['place_address'], $_POST['place_city'], $_POST['place_zip_code'], $_POST['place_province']
```

They are all part of the form that is submitted from the user from the front-end.

Comment: Hello! I'm unsure which part of this you're asking about, can you clarify which part specifically you're unsure of? Are you asking how to create a REST API endpoint that handles `POST` requests? Or are you saying you have one, but don't know how to make the request? If you're creating a custom endpoint yourself you would save them by saving them, aka creating the post yourself, saving the post meta yourself.

Comment: Hi Tom, I need help with the custom endpoint request, I have created one with a callback that is supposed to take the `$request` data and process it. I'm not sure about the data processing, I want to store all the form fields as post meta but as I know, i can't use the `update_post_meta` without a post id?

Comment: So you have a working endpoint, but you don't know how to call make a request to it in javascript? Javascript doesn't have an `update_post_meta` function. Or have our wires crossed and you mean you know how to make the request, but you don't know how to implement the endpoint? As  I said, you need to create the post yourself, if you're making your own rest endpoint you have to do all of that yourself.

Comment: Nope, I've implemented the endpoint and I'm using axios and vue from the other host to fetch the data from the wp that serve as backend. I understand that I need to use the `wp_insert_post` and the `update_post_meta` inside the endpoint callback. What I need to understand is if I need to pass any authentication information to the endpoint or if I need to use the `wp_ajax_nopriv_`  hook when the data are passed. The form will be accessible to all users so I don't need to ckeck for user roles or similar, I want just save the passed datainto the db to use them later.

Comment: hmmm `wp_ajax_nopriv` has nothing to do with the REST API, that's the legacy admin AJAX interface, and you need to authenticate if you've asked for it to authenticate. I think we've got our wires crossed, and that there's a huge number of assumptions being made that you've not stated. If you've implemented a bespoke endpoint via `register_rest_route`, can you include it in your question? Also, you've mentioned a lot of pieces of information in the comments, can you edit your question to include all the  information that's relevant?

Comment: @TomJNowell I've updated the question with the basic information that will be passed from the front-end form to wordpress remote backend using axios. At the moment I haven't write yet the saving function inside the callback

Comment: So you're asking  how to write the save code? Keep in mind you need to ask a **specific** question, and ask it clearly, this question is very cloudy unclear and ambiguous, it's not obvious what part is  the question, and what part is just background information. Based on your follow up edit, I suspect your question is: "How do I create a post in code then add post meta to it?"

Comment: no, i'm not asking this. I just want to understand how i can concatenate the wp_insert_post and the update_post_meta function.

Comment: So you want to create a post but also update  its post meta all in one single function call? If that's the case then all the REST API  stuff is a huge distraction that just confuses people reading your quesiton :( Why can't you just call `wp_insert_post` then call `update_post_meta`?

Comment: The rest API is the core to serve data to the remote application, since I'm using vue.js and axios, I only want to understand if after a post request, the custom endpoint and these two function are suits my needings. That's all.

Comment: Then I honestly have no idea what your question is. You know how to make the request, you know how to handle the request with `wp_insert_post` to create the post, and how to set up the post meta by calling `update_post_meta`, I don't know what it is you're asking. Are you just looking for reassurance?